# Checking if a tuple is in range

Tags: python, python-3.x, comparison-operators

In my level editing program, I have the following code, which removes game pieces that have moved out of the playable area:

```
x, y = theobj.pos
if x not in range(0,79):
    level.remove_obj(theobj)
if y not in range(0,29):
    level.remove_obj(theobj)
```

Is there any efficient way I can simplify this to a single if statement? I've considered using list comprehension to generate a list of all valid position tuples, but that seems a little bit bloated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use:

```
if not (0 <= x <= 78 and 0 <= y <= 28):
    level.remove_obj(theobj)
```

This uses [chained comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#not-in) to test against two boundaries for both `x` and `y`.

I'd not create `range()` objects here; you are creating a new object for each test.

Demo:

```
>>> x, y = 10, 10
>>> (0 <= x <= 78 and 0 <= y <= 28)
True
>>> x, y = 10, 42
>>> (0 <= x <= 78 and 0 <= y <= 28)
False
>>> x, y = 81, 10
>>> (0 <= x <= 78 and 0 <= y <= 28)
False
```

Comment: That's much nicer - though I do still have to unpack the tuple.

Comment: @Schilcote: you'll still have to unpack, or inline. `if not (0 <= theobj.pos[0] <= 78 and 0 <= theobj.pos[1] <= 28):` is not too bad.

Comment: @Dabrion: use a lambda *how*? To encapsulate the range check? That's still an extra line to define the lambda.

Comment: it is unclear if he want to code-golf it or if he wants a more efficient way. best way to filter a collection is to use itertools or list comprehensions. in both cases lambdas are handy.

Comment: lambda how? like that: `[obj for obj in col if (lambda x,y: 0<=x<=78 and 0<=y<=28)(*obj)]`

Comment: @Dabrion: No, can't say I find that a very readable approach.

Comment: @Schilcote I like unpacking, it's very explicit. The inline indexing (`theobj.pos[0]` instead of `x`) is ugly and the intent is not clear.

Comment: @RobertoBonvallet Yeah, the idea of simplifying the code is to make it more readable at a glance anyway, so sacrificing lines for readability is a false economy.